# Different output on Leap Year

Tags: python

I am confused here that two codes are showing different outputs.
Can anyone help me to figure out that what's wrong with 1st code...

**First Code:**
It's is showing the wrong output

```
print("Welcome to Leap Year Finder!")

year = int(input("Write a year to check..\n"))

div4by = year % 4
div100by = year % 100
div400by = year % 400

if(div4by == 0 and div100by == 0 and div400by == 0):
  print(f"Year {year} {div4by} {div100by} {div400by} is Leap Year!")
else:
  print(f"Year {year} {div4by} {div100by} {div400by} is Not Leap Year!")
```

**Second Code:**
It's working fine.

```
if div4by == 0:
  if div100by == 0:
    if div400by == 0:
      print("Leap year.")
    else:
      print("Not leap year.")
  else:
    print("Leap year.")
else:
  print("Not leap year.")
```

Comment: That is not a correct leap year calculations. A day divisible by 4 is *always* divisible by 400 so the check makes no sense. A leap year is a year divisible by 4 but *not*  by 100 except if it's divisible by 400

Comment: @mousetail Correction: *"A **year** divisible by **400** is always divisible by **4**"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct condition is

```
if div400by == 0 or div100by != 0 and div4by == 0:
```